# Ubuntu Script: do this, reboot, do that

Tags: scripts, reboot

I'm trying to automate some little installation process:

- List item
- apt install this
- reboot
- apt install that
- finish some other thing

Is there a way to get a script resumed after a reboot 
OR
some sort of desired state configuration

which lets me achieve that (without using any sort of server/cloud)?

Thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

First, add a line to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
/path/to/finishinstallscript
```

Your `/path/to/startinstallscript` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
list item
apt install this
reboot
```

Your `/path/to/finishinstallscript` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt install that
finish some other thing
echo "#!/bin/bash" > /path/to/finishinstallscript
exit 0
```

At reboot, the `finishinstallscript` is overwritten by an empty (well, just the shebang) line. Thus, after a second reboot, nothing is executed a second time. You will want to keep a copy of the original `finishinstallscript`, as it is lost after reboot.

The `exit 0` command is there to ensure the startup script ends properly (otherwise your system won't boot in case of failure).

Don't forget to make both scripts executable. It could also be useful to notify the user of what is happening with a `notify-send` message before rebooting.